# Convert UIImage to Monochrome 1 bit bmp image Swift 5.1

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing

PS: The result i wanted is in [Bool] format. ie, 0 for backgrounds and 1 for any color other than background.

I have an UIImage with 32 bits per pixel. How to make binary image (ie, 1bit .bmp image)

I'm using the code below: But its giving all zeros

```
  public extension UIImage {

        func pixelData() -> [UInt8]? {
                let size = self.size
                let dataSize = size.width * size.height
                var pixelData = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(dataSize))
                let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
                let context = CGContext(data: &pixelData,
                                        width: Int(size.width),
                                        height: Int(size.height),
                                        bitsPerComponent: 1,
                                        bytesPerRow:Int(size.width),
                                        space: colorSpace,
                                        bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipLast.rawValue)
                guard let cgImage = self.cgImage else { return nil }
                context?.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))

                return pixelData
            }
}
```

Comment: edited. which colorspace i have to use? grey style will work?

Answer (score 1):

I have created, maybe a little far fetched, a solution.

First, I have created a pixel struct, describing what a pixel represents.

```
struct Pixel {

    var r: Float
    var g: Float
    var b: Float
    var a: Float
    var row: Int
    var col: Int

    init(r: UInt8, g: UInt8, b: UInt8, a: UInt8, row: Int, col: Int) {
        self.r = Float(r)
        self.g = Float(g)
        self.b = Float(b)
        self.a = Float(a)
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
    }

    var color: UIColor {
        return UIColor(
            red: CGFloat(r/255.0), 
            green: CGFloat(g/255.0), 
            blue: CGFloat(b/255.0), 
            alpha: CGFloat(a/255.0)
        )
    }

    var description: String {
        return "\(r), \(g), \(b), \(a)"
    }

}
```

I then created a UIImage extension.

```
extension UIImage {

    var pixelData: [Pixel] {
        let bmp = self.cgImage!.dataProvider!.data
        var data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(bmp)
        var r, g, b, a: UInt8
        var pixels = [Pixel]()

        for row in 0 ..< Int(self.size.width) {
            for col in 0 ..< Int(self.size.height) {
                r = data.pointee
                data = data.advanced(by: 1)
                g = data.pointee
                data = data.advanced(by: 1)
                b = data.pointee
                data = data.advanced(by: 1)
                a = data.pointee
                data = data.advanced(by: 1)
                pixels.append(Pixel(r: r, g: g, b: b, a: a, row: row, col: col))
            }
        }
        return pixels
    }

    var monochrome: UIImage? {
        let context = CIContext(options: nil)
//        let currentFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectNoir")
        let currentFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorMonochrome")
        currentFilter?.setValue(CIImage(image: self), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        guard let output = currentFilter?.outputImage, 
              let cgImage = context.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent) else {
            print("Failed to create output image")
            return nil
        }
        return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: scale, orientation: imageOrientation)
    }

}
```

I did create the monochrome filter, you can see the commented code, you could use that to create a grayscale filter instead.

After that, all I had to do is test it and parse it:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "Test2")!

let grayScale: [Bool] = image.pixelData.map {
    var white: CGFloat = 0
    var alpha: CGFloat = 0

    $0.color.getWhite(&white, alpha: &alpha)
    return white > 0.5
}

var trues  = 0
var falses = 0

grayScale.forEach {
    if $0 {
        trues += 1
    } else {
        falses += 1
    }
}
```

The last step could be transformed into an extension too. Hope this helps!

Comment: how to generate bmp file from this array

Comment: You would need to construct your own bitmap format, as Apple doesn't really have true support for it. I would suggest you export it to `png` anyways, as that supports a broader platform anyways. More info on the tag here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format